# What about Dropzone.js within an existing form submitted by AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, dropzone.js

Ok, here is the scenario. I have already a form having some input fields, some radio buttons and an `input type=file`. There is a button for submitting the whole form using AJAX.

Everything was working fine, until i decided to change the `input type=file` with the more fancy DropZone.js

Now i have the following html code  (a sample here):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="test_form" name="test_form" class="form uniformForm">
       <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="a-name" id="a-name" />            
       <label for="a-name">Field Name</label>

       <div class="dropzone dropzone-previews" id="my-awesome-dropzone </div>
</form>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" id="submitForm"> Submit </button>
```

I have the following js (jQuery), too:

```
$("button#submitForm").click(function(){
    var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("test_form"));
    fd.append("label", "WEBUPLOAD");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "create_form.php",
        data: fd,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: false,   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    });
});

$("div#my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone({
   url: "#",
   paramName: "creative_file",
   maxFilesize: 1,
   autoProcessQueue: false
 });
```

In documentation of Dropzone.js says that the dropzone div looks like `<input type="file" name="file" />`. The only difference is that i want to rename the input name as creative_file.

I have 2 question.

1) This doesn't work. When pressing the Submit button, i have FIREBUG opened and i check what it sends as POST. It sends everything except the files. No creative_file, no file at all.

2) If finally figured out how to make it works, is there any way to have a fallback with this implementation especially for the iOS or Android devices ?

Comment: I agree there should be some documentation on how to implement in an existing form. Especially in Laravel Vue type applications.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
        $("#salvar").on('click',function(e) {           
            if ($("#psl_titulo").val() == "") {
                alert('Empty');
                } else {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0) { 
                    myDropzone.processQueue();  
                    } else {
                    $("#my-awesome-dropzone").submit(function(e)
                    {
                        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
                        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
                        $.ajax(
                        {
                            url : formURL,
                            type: "POST",
                            data : postData,
                            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                            {
                                window.location.href = url_redirect;
                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                            {
                                alert('Ocorreu um erro ao salvar ao enviar os dados. Erro: ' + textStatus);      
                            }
                        });
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                    $("#my-awesome-dropzone").submit();
                }
            }           
        });
```